# Redirect if url contain a string using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect lots of urls who contain a string `product-name.html`:

http://www.example.com/product-name.html?limit=9&manufacturer=202&mode=grid
http://www.example.com/product/product-name.html?id=213&limit=5&mode=grid

to one address: http://www.example.com/product-new/name.html

My rewrite rule looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.)product-name(.)$ /product-new/name.html [R=301,L]`

but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: `product-name` and `product-new` is dynamic?

Comment: `product-name` is dynamic, but `product-new` will be always the same

Comment: the whole `/product-new/name.html` will be always the same

Comment: I would like to redirect all of links who contain `product-name` in whole urls

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:

```
RewriteRule ^product-name.html$ /product-new/name.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product/product-name.html$ /product-new/name.html? [R=301,L]
```